# Accessing Dict item error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

So I was writing a class for processing data items from a dictionary of items. Here I am having this error:

> The code of dictionary function is (in brief)

```
def preProcess():
    dataset = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(items')):
        dataset[v['image_id']] = {'image' : v['file_name']}, { 
                                  'texts' : {i : v['sent']}}
                    
    return dataset
```

> The code of accessing the dictionary item is

```
for idx, val in enumerate(data):
    print(self.data[idx]['image'])
```

The dictionary function works perfectly but when I try to access the items, it gives following error:

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Its considering the dict as a tuple I guess. I am new to such data structures of Python. Could anyone please point out where the issue is? Am I inserting or declaring dictionary items wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the print from the code to access the dictionary write correctly? I mean, it should be ```print(self.data[idx]['image'])```

Comment: @escris I am sorry thats just a typo. Yes, its written in my code as you have written in your comment. Would be glad if you could help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Then, i guess data is the dictionary returned in preProcess method. So i would recommend you use data.items() instead of enumerate(data), it returns the key and it's value, furthermore, you could use ```for key, value in data[v["image_id]"].items()``` and every iteration you get the key and it's value. As you say, you are still a beginner so i would debug your code to know the value of each variable you are setting and realize if it is as you want.

Comment: @Escris is my definition of dict correct? Why is it throwing an error of tuple?

Comment: I would say that it's not correct. First, is not necessary to do dataset = {} if you do dataset[v["image_id"]] = ...... because you are already declaring its value there. Anyways, i guess dataset[v["image_id"]] is wrong too. If you could provide more information about the value of "items", i could help you since there's no context of what you want to do.

Comment: `'1' = ({'image': 'COCO_train2014_000000131074_319598.jpg'}, {'texts': {1: 'a long bed at the side of wall'}})` This is one index value of the items dict. Could you please help me now? Thanks a lot! @Escris

Comment: Please fix your question. Your code has syntax errors (a single quote, unbalanced parentheses), `self.data` versus `data`,... Please define `items` with a sample value, and call the function, all in one script, so we can run it and reproduce the problem. Right now it is not entirely clear what your input is, and the function return value relates to the iteration code. Moreover, if you debug your code (set break points and inspect variables), this should be easy to resolve.

Comment: Please @Fc0001, follow trincot advise. The output you told me is the expected one or it is what you are getting? Because if you check the parenthesis, that's a tuple, with 2 values, the first dict and the second one.

Comment: Hi @Escris Problem solved. Thank you. `dataset = defaultdict(dict)
dataset[w['image_id']]['image'] = v['file_name']
dataset[w['image_id']]['texts'] = {}
dataset[w['image_id']]['texts'][inner_i] = inner_v['sent']`

Comment: @trincot I know what you mean. But the code is confidential so I had to reveal only part of it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my dictionary initialization was not correct. I solved the issue by importing collections.defaultdict

```
dataset = defaultdict(dict)
dataset[w['image_id']]['image'] = v['file_name']
dataset[w['image_id']]['texts'] = {}
dataset[w['image_id']]['texts'][inner_i] = inner_v['sent']
```